# Getting shadow in transparent window in Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I'm new to Electron, while creating transparent window I got this type of shadow:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put hasShadow false while creating a window.

```html
  const menubarWindow = new BrowserWindow({  
      frame: false,
      hasShadow: false,
      fullscreenable: false,
      alwaysOnTop: true,
      resizable: false,
      minimizable: false,
      maximizable: false,
      transparent: true,
      titleBarStyle: 'customButtonsOnHover',
      closable: false,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        webSecurity: false,
      },
    })
```